# Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk]

Tags: android, sdk, environment-variables, exit-code, panic

There is another `ERROR: Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1`

I have already defined the environment variables. `(ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and even ANDROID_HOME)` but it is still not working

I tried also with or without `ANDROID_HOME`. it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a value problem in conf of SDK. Mostly on 32Bit Version it bugged me. But i kicked off this lame duck, because the concept of google looks like a softocide.